# Google Maps Javascript API v3 was disabled in application

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an application which use google map api v3(I run it on the localhost), every things run well still this morning, I opened my app and saw the error: `Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key`
I followed the given link to solve this problem.However, after did these:

```
1. Visit the APIs Console at https://code.google.com/apis/console and log in with your Google Account.
2. Click the Services link from the left-hand menu.
3. Activate the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 service.
4. Click the API Access link from the left-hand menu. Your API key is available from the API Access page, in the Simple API Access section. Maps API applications use the Key for browser apps.
```

nothing change in my app, and I still didn't overcome the issue. So can someone tell me exactly how can I do.

Answer (score 0):

If you've gone through that document, created an API key for yourself then in your application your script source should look something like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=21a300d4a9a2cf55e4ffac1750acbc01" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You will just replace the "key=YOURAPIKEY". This is how Google tracks who is using its service.